# How to handle Textview Link click in Android?

Tags: android

I have a html set to textview using Html.fromHtml and want handle when click link a href.
I want get link and text content of link.
Ex:

[StackOver](http://stackoverflow.com)

Output: http://stackoverflow.com + StackOver.

I find many solution on stackover but not help for me.I only get link, cant get context text of link.

Please help me.

This is code me (only get link):

```
protected void makeLinkClickable(final SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder, final URLSpan span, final String title, final int lenght) {
    int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
    int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);
    ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Toast.makeText(context, span.getURL(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
    strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}

protected void setTextViewHTML(TextView text, String html, String title) {
    CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
    URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for (URLSpan span : urls) {
        makeLinkClickable(strBuilder, span, title, urls.length);
    }
    text.setText(strBuilder);
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear,Please explain it properly.@Cheng

Comment: I want handle link in textview android.When click link then i can get link and content link. Ex: "<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Hello</a> ...I want get output is: link : http://stackoverflow.com and content text: Hello.

Comment: String temp="<a href=\"stackoverflow.com\">Hello</a>";
        temp=temp.replaceAll("<a href=\"","").replaceAll("\">",",").replaceAll("</a>","");
        String[] valueArray=temp.split(",");
        String link=valueArray[0];
        String contentText=valueArray[1];